# Return status of perl script

Tags: perl

I came across the following script,

```
$num=53535.35353535;

$result1=printf("Result = %.2f\n",$num);
print "$result1 \n";
print $?;   # prints the return status
```

Output of the script is,

```
53535.35
1
0
```

I see return status of print is stored in `$result1` which is 1. Since print executed fine it is success and its true condition is displayed as 1. Whereas the return status of the script is in `$?` which is 0.

Is both 1 and 0 true in this script? please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: What external program do you think Perl is running in order to populate `$?`?  From the documentation:  *"The status returned by the last pipe close, backtick (``) command, successful call to wait() or waitpid(), or from the system() operator."*  None of these are happening in this script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) does not specify the return value of `printf`, so it's pointless to capture and evaluate it. It seems to be 1, whatever you do.

As to `$?`, it shows the exit status of the last external program you ran via `system` or backticks, etc. You don't run any external program, so it's meaningless too.

BTW, you have to be careful with exit statuses, because `0` means success, anything else is error. `system` also returns the exit status of the external program, and you might be tempted to do this:

```
system "someprogram" or print "Error in someprogram\n";
```

This is wrong, as `0` means success, but Perl treats zero as false. Instead it should be:

```
system "someprogram" and print "Error in someprogram\n";
```

which is kind of counter-intuitive and difficult to read. So it's even better to do this:

```
print "Error in someprogram\n" if system "someprogram" != 0;
```

Comment: `printf` returns true on success, false on error, setting `$!` on error. `perl -E'close(STDOUT) if $ARGV[0]; say(STDERR printf("%s\n", "test") ? "ok" : $!);'` (Pass 0, then 1 as an argument.)